# C# Console Disable Resize

Tags: c#, windows-console

How to achieve programmatically that the console window is not resizable.

I don't want user to change the console window size with their mouse.

Answer (score 4):

See the answer in [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1aa43c6c-71b9-42d4-aa00-60058a85f0eb/c-console-window-disable-resize?forum=csharpgeneral) on MSDN. It requires p-invoking:

```
private const int MF_BYCOMMAND = 0x00000000;
public const int SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;
public const int SC_MINIMIZE = 0xF020;
public const int SC_MAXIMIZE = 0xF030;
public const int SC_SIZE = 0xF000;//resize

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int DeleteMenu(IntPtr hMenu, int nPosition, int wFlags);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IntPtr handle = GetConsoleWindow();
    IntPtr sysMenu = GetSystemMenu(handle, false);

    if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        DeleteMenu(sysMenu, SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
        DeleteMenu(sysMenu, SC_MINIMIZE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
        DeleteMenu(sysMenu, SC_MAXIMIZE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
        DeleteMenu(sysMenu, SC_SIZE, MF_BYCOMMAND);//resize
    }
    Console.Read();
}
```

<sup>Note that this does not prevent Windows window snapping (e.g. dragging window to edge of screen, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>)</sup>

Since you're trying to disable resizing, I'm guessing you won't want scrollbars either. For that, see this answer to [Remove space left after console scrollbars in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58381272/2799848) (leftover after matching `Console.SetWindowSize` and `SetBufferSize`; also requires p-invoking to "fix").

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure you can avoid that kind of action.
But you may try to use WindowHeight, WindowWidth, LargestWindowHeight and LargestWindowWidth.
See this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.console(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Not the first two initial settings (Height/Width)... You can try also *Console.SetWindowSize(width, height)* but I guess it cannot avoid user to redim the window - unless you check it manually all time and set according your needs.

Comment: You added those two after my comment. And indeed, none of those work to disallow resizing.